# Comparing geometries using Search Cursors

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, geometry, cursor

I'm working on a little arcpy script to compare the geometry of features (linked by a matching ID field

I've got a couple of search cursors populating dictionaries for the two feature classes which I then am trying to compare to find where features (that should be identical shapes) don't match.

I have run into a snag in my concept though in that the output from `SHAPE@` is returning `False` when I compare the features I know are identical (should return `True`).

```
import arcpy
fields = ['LineID', 'SHAPE@']
x = 'Line1' # Feature Class #1
y = 'Line2' # Feature Class #2
xDict = dict()
yDict = dict()
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(x, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        xDict[row[0]] = row[1]
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(y, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        yDict[row[0]] = row[1]
```

When I test I get `False` returned:

```
xDict[1] == yDict[1]
> False
```

This returns `False` even though I know that record #1 is identical in both feature classes.

Is there another way I can use my search cursors to compare the shape of the two features?  I know there are `.WKB`, `.WKT`, `.JSON` options for Shape - are these valid options for a comparison?  My brief testing suggests they are, but I'm unsure whether there are occasions where they would also return `False`.

```
xDict[1].WKB == yDict[1].WKB
> True
```

[image]

```
xDict[1].equals(yDict[1]) # Should be True
> True
xDict[2].equals(yDict[2]) # Should be False
> True
xDict[4].equals(yDict[4]) # Should be False
> False
```

Comment: A comparison for equivalence compares the objects, not their contents.  You want the `equals` operator.

Comment: @Vince by `equals` operator do you mean `xDict[1] is yDict[1]`?  This also returns `False`

Comment: No, `shape1.equals(shape2)`

Comment: @Vince OK thanks - that returns `True` even for one of the features that should return `False` (although it does return `False` for another feature correctly)

Comment: The one where it returns `True` incorrectly - the lines look the same, but they are drawn in the opposite direction

Comment: Since the description is: **Indicates if the base and comparison geometries are of the same shape type and define the same set of points in the plane.** it looks like `True` is a correct result (it probably does an `intersect` under the hood, and if the result matches either, they're equivalent -- this would probably also apply to rings with a different start point).  If you want vertex equivalence, you might be better off with WKB comparison.

Comment: Have you considered using sets instead of dictionaries?  Then you can just compare the sets (i.e. difference, symmetrical difference, etc.)

Comment: @jbalk how?  I use dictionaries so I can compare feature by feature based on an ID field.

Comment: Sorry I didn't think about that part.  I was just wondering if treating the Shape@ attribute differently would help, but sets won't help here.  Have you tried casting Shape@ as a string?  You mentioned WKB/WKT - I tested WKT and it works.  I haven't tested whether it works for lines going opposite directions tho.

Comment: I've always done my feature comparisons by breaking down into vertices and then compare all vertices from feature 1 to feature 2 then feature 2 to feature 1 - as soon as a non-matching vertex is found break and return false, that will get you through faster with features that are obviously different. @Vince is correct, the shape1.equals(shape2) should be what you're after but be aware that due to coordinate rounding two databases may give shapes that are different in micrometres; this is why I do my own vert-vert check, so I can control what's 'close enough'.

Comment: Does this *have* to be arcpy Midavalo? I have some working VB.net code that flags changed features (outside of given tolerance)... from a tool I wrote a few years ago to update 'has changed' attribution on bulk - to take the onus off operators updating these fields as they edited. I did write this before I found Feature Compare http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000004000000 and Detect Feature Changes http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Detect_Feature_Changes/001700000190000000/ tools, which may do what you're after.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson unfortunately arcpy is preferred due to it being a part of a bigger tool.  As far as I can tell though using `.WKB` should work - it's returned the correct expected result each time I've tried it.  Will confirm tomorrow and post as an answer if nothing else comes up before then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still think there should be a better way to do this, but this is what I've come up with, using `SHAPE@WKB` for the comparison of the shapes (matched on `FeatID`) in my two feature classes.

Here are my shapes - The arrows point at the start location:

[image]

And my script, including a description of what should be returned for each shape:

```
import arcpy

x = r'D:\temp\SE\CompareShapes\Data.gdb\TestPoly1'
y = r'D:\temp\SE\CompareShapes\Data.gdb\TestPoly2'

fields = ['FeatID', 'SHAPE@']
xDict = dict()
yDict = dict()
testDict = {
            1 : 'True - Identical',
            2 : 'False - Same shape, different start point',
            3 : 'True - Identical',
            4 : 'False - Same shape, different start point',
            5 : 'True - Identical',
            6 : 'False - Same shape, different start point',
            7 : 'False - Same shape, extra vertex',
            8 : 'False - Shape shape, different position (rotated)',
            9 : 'True - Identical'
           }

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(x, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        xDict[row[0]] = row[1]

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(y, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        yDict[row[0]] = row[1]

# Only 1, 3, 5, 9 are identical and should return True - rest should return False
for xx in xDict:
    print "Feature:        {}".format(xx) # FeatID of feature
    print "Expected:       {}".format(testDict[xx]) # Description of expected result
    print "x.equals(y):    {}".format(xDict[xx].equals(yDict[xx])) # Does the SHAPE@ equal SHAPE@?
    print "x.WKB == y.WKB: {}".format(xDict[xx].WKB == yDict[xx].WKB) # Does the WKB equal for each SHAPE@?
```

This returns the following output, which shows that `x.equals(y)` doesn't always return the required/expected value, and `x.WKB == y.WKB` seems to consistently return the expected value:

```
Feature:        1  
Expected:       True - Identical  
x.equals(y):    True  
x.WKB == y.WKB: True  
Feature:        2  
Expected:       False - Same shape, different start point  
x.equals(y):    True  
x.WKB == y.WKB: False  
Feature:        3
Expected:       True - Identical
x.equals(y):    True
x.WKB == y.WKB: True
Feature:        4
Expected:       False - Same shape, different start point
x.equals(y):    True
x.WKB == y.WKB: False
Feature:        5
Expected:       True - Identical
x.equals(y):    True
x.WKB == y.WKB: True
Feature:        6
Expected:       False - Same shape, different start point
x.equals(y):    True
x.WKB == y.WKB: False
Feature:        7
Expected:       False - Same shape, extra vertex
x.equals(y):    True
x.WKB == y.WKB: False
Feature:        8
Expected:       False - Shape shape, different position (rotated)
x.equals(y):    False
x.WKB == y.WKB: False
Feature:        9
Expected:       True - Identical
x.equals(y):    True
x.WKB == y.WKB: True
```

Comment: There is no point in having the Python equivalence operator listed, unless you want to test `x == x`

Comment: @Vince - Just outlining what I tested and the result

Comment: You didn't test `1 == 0`?  If you remove nine superfluous lines, a scrollbar wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @Vince fair comment - edited.

Comment: Excellent answer, well researched and practically proven. I was surprised at the return values of x.equals(y), according to the docs many of those True values should have been False. +1 from me.